# Find the unseen numbers of two tokens after then have been tossed, given sums

Tags: probability, coin-tossing

The puzzle is as follows:

> Over a table there are two flat tokens. Each one has a number written
> in both of their faces. If both chips are tossed and the remaining
> numbers seen to the eye are added together, the results are $38$,
> $41$, $50$ and $53$. The figure from below shows the result of one of
> these tosses. If the numbers of the faces which are unseen are $x$ and
> $y$. What will be the greatest positive difference of $x$ and $y$?

[image: Two coins: a yellow one labeled "24" and a blue one labeled "29"]

The alternatives are as follows:

1. 4
2. 14
3. 13
4. 3

What sort of logic should be used to find the difference? Is there a way to relate the sums from the faces of the tokens to what is shown? What is a a step by step approach on how to get the most likely numbers unseen in the chips?

Comment: This appears to be both a mathematics *problem* rather than a puzzle, and a question from another source that has not been credited. For both of those reasons, this question has been closed.

Comment: @Deusovi I think it is in the boundary. By the way I read the link which has been mentioned on the top. And the answer which has the most upvotes is the one which does say that a math puzzle is about ingenuity. Which I believe this question does. But there are other answers which have less upvotes and give other opinions. It does confuse me. I believe this question should be reopened.

Comment: The short solution is this: x+y must be 38 (I'll leave the proof for you), then either x+29 is 41 (and y+24 is 50) or x+29 is 50 (and y+24 is 41). The first will result x=12 and y=26 while the second will result x=21 and y=17. Now we know the answer is 14.

Comment: $x+y+x+29+y+24=38+41+50=129\implies x+y=38\implies x,y=19\pm k$. Therefore $|x-y|=|2k|$. $k=2,-7$ by inspection, therefore answer is **B:14**.

Comment: @athin Gee I wish I could find a way how to prove what you mentioned that $38$ is equal to $x+y$. How did arrived to that?. I'm stuck on that.

Comment: @JMP Why did you add a second time $x+y$ in the left side of your equation?. I'm confused the side which is not seen to the eye can have different values?. Can you please add an additional comment so I can understand better?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell the proof: let's say the sides of the coins are: x,y,a,b. Here it's known that a=24 and b=29. Now we have 4 sums: x+y, x+b, a+y, a+b. Note that, (x+y)+(a+b) = (x+b)+(a+y). As we know the 4 sums are 38, 41, 50, 53; then two sums = the other two sums. In this case, 38+53=41+50. Therefore, as (a+b)=53, (x+y) must be 38. The next step will be dividing the 2 cases: x+b=41 (and a+y=50) or x+b=50 (and a+y=41).

Comment: @athin Why is it 4 sums and not 6?. I thought it was x+y, x+a, x+b, y+a, y+b, a+b?. What does trim down those alternatives for the sums?. Can you explain this part please?. How do I conclude that two sums are equal to the other two sums?. Can you explain this as well?. Or is it just something that you spot from looking the numbers?.

Comment: If x is behind 24 and y is behind 29, then we are given that the four possible outcomes are 24+29, 24+y, 29+x, x+y. We know these are 38,41,50,53, but we don't know in which order. But we do know that their sums must be equal, so in full: (24+29)+(24+y)+(29+x)+(x+y)=38+41+50+53. After simplifying this, we get x+y=38.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell there are two coins, each having two sides, meaning 2x2=4 possible sums..

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't look at this as a probability question. What I'd do is (with small correction pointed out by @anodyne):

> 1. Make 6 columns. 3 for the remaining results and 2 for $x$ and $y$. So $24+x$, $29+y$, $x+y$. And then 1 for $|x-y|$.
>  2. List all the possible results for $24+x$ and $29+y$ in the rows. There are at most 6 possibilities, since they must be two of the remaining three numbers.
>  3. Fill out the rest of the table and look down the $x-y$ row for the result. Some of the rows might be eliminated if the $x+y$ is not the third number.

So to elaborate further, here's the basic template that you would need to fill out:

> [image: table outline]

I fill out the details in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dqlApyhXV_Y0nlB5OmYa5VAABYVDxjRuD0dVw_K83GM/edit?usp=sharing):

> [image: filled out table]

This is the "brute force" way of working it out and gets the job done with a minimum of fuss. However, the table shows that $x,y\in(41,51)$. So let's prove that. Suppose $A,B,C$ are the numbers $38,41,50$ in some order. And suppose that $A=24+x$, $B=29+y$, and $C=x+y$ ($x$ is the number opposite the 29 and $y$ is the number opposite the 24). Then $A+B = 53+x+y=53+C$. The only way that could work is if $C=38$, so $A,B\in(41,50)$.

That means that there are only two rows that need to be looked at (the green ones in the diagram), and you can choose the biggest answer for $|x-y|$ from there.

Comment: This seems like a clear-headed way to approach this. I would cut off two of those columns, as a token's visible side isn't to be added with its other side. So technically only 3 "remaining results." But agreed on everything else, especially with removing the probability tag.

Comment: @DrXorile Do it exist a way to bypass the necesity to filling out a table?. Can it be solved just by inspection or anything?.

Comment: @DrXorile I'm still stuck on how to fill out those eight columns you mention. Can you show an example of how would the first column and row would look like?.

Comment: Without the question reopening, this would be cumbersome to visualize. Simply put, just treat X as the other side of the 24-token and Y as the other side of the 29-token. Then (24+Y), (X+29), and (X+Y) must take on one of {38, 41, 50}. There are only so many possibilities for what X and Y could be - I suggest doing it by hand yourself. Once you do so, you'll find that @athin's answer above is correct.

Comment: @anodyne I don't get the part of why $x+y$ must be $38$, $41$ or $50$?. Where in the problem does it say this?. I don't know how can I conclude this part?.

Comment: There are four possible arrangements of the tokens and four sums, so...